# Symfony2 form validation - ensuring one integer is lower than another

Tags: validation, symfony

I have a case for you. I have an entity that contains two integers. Both are between 0 and 100, but one is the minimum value and one is the maximum value. Therefore, the max value should be greater than or equal to the min value.

I have had a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

In the last of these links we have the following example:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Validator/Constraints/ContainsAlphanumericValidator.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ContainsAlphanumericValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Za0-9]+$/', $value, $matches)) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
        }
    }
}
```

But this takes the $value, and I need to compare the min and max to each other. How do I reference the "min" value inside the "max" validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the callback constraint to use your own logic to compare the values and add a violation if needed. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html